# Is sed line deletion atomic?

Tags: linux, multithreading, shell, sed

Lets say I have a file 'queue'. From what I understand, appending to it using '>>' is atomic as defined by POSIX. But if I have multiple processes appending, is it safe to do the following without data loss?

`sed -e '1d' -i queue`

I have several different script services on Linux that may want to pass information between them. Each has a 'queue' where new data is pushed on the bottom with the next item to be popped from the top.

Is my use of sed guaranteed to not miss an append operation from another process between the time it reads the file to a buffer and writes it to back to disk?

Thanks.

Comment: I will let other, clever, folk tell you the answer, but if not, you can use `sem` from `GNU Parallel` in front of the `sed` command as a mutex to ensure that only one runs at a time...

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of the sem program. This doesn't answer the question as you said, but I've learned something new and voted you up for it.

Comment: Are you sure that the program is called `sem`? I run RHEL7 and `yum whatprovides sem` doesn't return a result.

Comment: On my Mac it is a hard link to `parallel`.

Comment: Use of `>>` is not at all atomic.  Writes of less than a certain size are atomic, but a program that is writing to a file will likely be block buffering and may defer writes until they are 4096 or 8192 bytes, and it is extremely likely that the block boundary will not align with a line (ie, the last byte written will not be a newline), and the writes will split lines if another processs is writing at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll defer to anyone else who makes a stronger claim, but I think it is not safe to use that way.  `-i` works by making a temporary copy of the file and then moving that back in place, which would replace any additional changes in the middle.

Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

> -i[SUFFIX]
>   --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>   This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. GNU sed does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output.1.
>   This option implies -s.
>
> When the end of the file is reached, the temporary file is renamed to the output file's original name. The extension, if supplied, is used to modify the name of the old file before renaming the temporary file, thereby making a backup copy2).
>
> This rule is followed: if the extension doesn't contain a *, then it is appended to the end of the current filename as a suffix; if the extension does contain one or more * characters, then each asterisk is replaced with the current filename. This allows you to add a prefix to the backup file, instead of (or in addition to) a suffix, or even to place backup copies of the original files into another directory (provided the directory already exists).
>
> If no extension is supplied, the original file is overwritten without making a backup.

Comment: It's true. `sed -i` is definitely not atomic. For larger files, the critical section can even take minutes or hours.